# Commercial API - RapidAPI

Tags: imgur, rapidapi

I'm a user of a android app that uploads images to imgur though the commercial API portal RapidAPI. The ability to upload hasn't been working for several days now.

Looking at the Imgur API status board it looks like everything is working fine. All incidents have been successfully resolved.

A help ticket has been filled on the RapidAPI website but as of yet there doesn't seem to be any response.

Is the commercial API down? If so is there any feedback on whether the problem will be resolved soon?

Answer (score 1):

This should be working by now. Imgur last updated their API a few months ago on RapidAPI Hub and all endpoints are working.

If the problem still persists, you can try contacting the RapidAPI support team at support@rapidapi.com